# When to process data from Observables in angular?

Tags: angular, observable

I have a service

```
export class FoodService {

  private foodUrl: string = "/url/to/data";
  foodList: Food[];

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getFoodList(): Observable<Food[]>
  {
    return this.http.get(this.foodUrl)
      .map(response => response.json() as Food[]);
  }
}
```

which returns an `Observable<Food[]>`.

In a component I subscribe to the returned `Observable`. I do this in the `ngOnInit()`-function:

```
export class ResultComponent implements OnInit {

  foodList: Food[];

  constructor(private foodService: FoodService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tags = this.optionService.tags;

    this.foodService.getFoodList()
      .subscribe(list => this.foodList = list);
  }
}
```

This all works just fine. But now I want to process the `foodList` and I keep getting errors because at the time of the processing it is still undefined. I even tried passing my processing function as `onCompleted` parameter in the `subscribe` call.

Is there a way to wait till the data is fetched?

//edit:
In my processing step I loop the Array and count some things. The Error origins from `forEach`:

```
 evaluateTags(): void
  {
    this.foodList.forEach(
    //list.forEach(
      food =>
      {
        var count: number = 0;

        this.tags.forEach(
          tag =>
          {
            if (food.tags.includes(tag))
            {
              count++;
            }
          }
        );

        food.hitrate = count / food.tags.length;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: What is the code for processing the `foodList`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: added the processing step

Comment: @AJT_82 Not a duplicate. The said question doesn't contain the solution for observables.

Comment: @estus It contains all the necessary info. OP is making an async call whether it's an observable or a promise and the tl;dr answer for all is: inside the callback.

Comment: @echonax It doesn't contain sufficient info. Inside which callback? `map`? `do`? `subscribe`? The question contains specific details and it deserves a specific answer. Over-duping is evil.

Comment: @estus Hmm maybe you are right. Lacked the sense of emphaty there.

Comment: @estus, (wasn't my intention to be evil in any way), maybe we should find a dupe that answers this more *precisely*, there are probably hundreds of these questions here I think :P I'll find one and bookmark it for future use :)

Comment: @echonax, write up a self answered question about this issue, as well as the `cannot read blah of undefined` regarding template, it would be really useful here to have one of each :) I assign this honorable task for you, you are very welcome :P No but really, someone really should do this :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Thank you :D I'll do it..

Comment: @echonax Sure, I'll empty the bottle/pint for you while you do the work :D

Comment: @AJT_82 lol I'll just edit the last part

Comment: @echonax, well I see that now... and now I look insane, talking to myself about a bottle :D Oh well, better stop chitchatting anyway, before someone has some remarks on that :P

Comment: @AJT_82 agreed good sir : p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the processing in the subscribe?

```
    this.foodService.getFoodList()
    .subscribe(list => {
      this.foodList = list;
      this.evaluateTags();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I tried this before but I had a malformed entry in my database..... so my bad